# JPA code not executing further after transaction.commit

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

Main method

```
    EntityManagerFactory emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("manager1");
    EntityManager em1=emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction entityTransaction=em1.getTransaction();
    entityTransaction.begin();

    Person persons=JPA_basic_Example.setPerson();//fills all the fields of person
    Credential cred=JPA_basic_Example.setCredential();//fills all fields of credentials

    System.out.println("check1");
    cred.setPerson(persons);
    persons.setCredential(cred);
    em1.persist(cred);
    entityTransaction.commit();
    em1.close();
    emf.close();
```

Java Bean Credential oneToone Bidirectional with Person

```
public class Credential {
    @Id
    @Column(name ="credentialid")
    private int credential_id;
    private  String UserName;

    private String Password;


    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="Personid")
    private Person person;

    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        Password = password;
    }

    public int getCredential_id() {
        return credential_id;
    }

    public void setCredential_id(int credential_id) {
        this.credential_id = credential_id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return UserName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        UserName = userName;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }
}
```

Java Bean Person

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name ="Personid")
    private int person_id;

    //@Basic(optional = false)
    //@Column(name ="Name", unique = true)
    private  String name;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable
    List<String> contact=new ArrayList<String>();

    private Address address=new Address();

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "person",  orphanRemoval = true )
    Credential credential ;


    public Credential getCredential() {
        return credential;
    }

    public void setCredential(Credential credential) {
        this.credential = credential;
    }


    public List<String> getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(List<String> contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }


    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPerson_id() {
        return person_id;
    }




    public void setPerson_id(int person_id) {
        this.person_id = person_id;
    }
}
```

Output Console

Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        Person
        (area, city, pincode, state, name, Personid) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
AFter this code stuck and nit moving forward nor showing any exceptions or errors

Comment: what is "stuck" ? if there is a deadlock then provide the java thread dump

Comment: Question solved it was some issue with connection and after restarting it is working finr